# dynamic update input text value

Tags: jquery

I try to make > 1. type in `input` dynamic update value in new layer >
2. click layer the value show in the input and can be edit again.
http://jsfiddle.net/8yZhf/3/

but I'm stuck in 2., if use `$('.input').off("focus")` to avoid add new layer(not update),
 when finish edit and `focusout`, how to recover the `focus` just like before? or any better idea?

```
var layer;
$('.input').focus(function(){
    layer = $('.input_insert').children('div').length + 1;
    $('<div class='+layer+'></div>').appendTo('.input_insert');// add layer

    $('.input_insert').children('div').click(function(e){
        $('.input').val($(e.target).html());
        // $('.input').off("focus");
    })
    return layer;// return layer count for keyup, focusout
})
$('.input').keyup(function(e){
    $('.'+layer).html(this.value);
})
$('.input').focusout(function(){
    $("input[class='input']").val('');
    if($('.'+layer).html() == ''){// check if empty
        $('.'+layer).remove();
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<div class="input_insert"></div>// container
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yZhf/4/)**

There was a simple issue at first in your code. You were re-assigning a click event to every element with this code here

```
$('.input_insert').children('div').click(function(){
    $('.input').val($('.'+layer).html());
    // $('.input').off("focus");
})
```

so the first issue was to address only having the new element wired to a click event.

The next issue was that since there was only one variable tracking layer, only the most current layer was ever used. This can be addressed by implementing an extra tracking variable.

html same as above

js

```
var layer;
var target = -1;//when not -1, this indicates a layer is being edited
$('.input').focus(function(){
 layer = $('.input_insert').children('div').length + 1;
 //save the value of the layer for use on click event
 var current = layer;
 $('<div class='+layer+'></div>').appendTo('.input_insert');// add layer
 //wire click only to the new layer
 $('.'+current).click(function(){
  $('.input').val($(this).html());
  //indicate that this layer is the edit target when clicked
  target = current;
 });
 return layer;// return layer count for keyup, focusout
});
$('.input').keyup(function(e){
 //check if there is a layer being edited
 if( target > -1 ){//layer edit
   $('.'+target).html(this.value);
 }else{//new layer
  $('.'+layer).html(this.value);
 }
});
$('.input').focusout(function(){
 //reset target because there is no current edit
 target = -1;
 $("input[class='input']").val('');
  if($('.'+layer).html() == ''){// check if empty
   $('.'+layer).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly different way

```
$('input').on('keypressed', function(e) {
   $('.input_insert:last-child').text($(this).val())  
}).on('blur', function(e) {
   var val = $(this).val() 
   , lastInsert = $('.input_insert:last-child').text('')
   , newInsert = $('<div />').addClass('input_insert')
                             .text(val).insertBefore(lastInsert) 
   $(this).val('')
})
```